# Olingo: how to implement groupby and aggregations on server

Tags: olingo

I've been digging on google in order to find documentation or any stuff helping code in order to make an olingo server that handles aggregations, groupby...

I don't quite figure out reading documentation and I don't find any other documentation over there.

Please, anybody can help me, please?